# Errors involving precedence of modulus operator and brackets with large numbers in C++

Tags: c++, modulus, integer-overflow, largenumber

The first part of the just computes some mathematical formula, stroed in *ans1*, *ans2* and *ans3*. Many sites give % and * as having the same priority in the precedence order. Should we then consider them left to right in an expression? Only difference between line 56 and 57 is the order in which the terms in the product have used and also an addition pair of brackets are being used. I don't understand how this makes a difference to the final result.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define mod 998244353

int main()
{
int ans1 = 672510887; // These are the outputs for the previous part of the program
int ans2 = 814503527;
int ans3 = 71242790;

cout << ans1%mod << endl; // Returns the same number for all three as they are lesser than mod
cout << ans2%mod << endl;
cout << ans3%mod << endl;
cout << 1LL*ans1*ans2*ans3 << endl; // 4021307808285681478
cout << 1LL * ( 1LL * ans1%mod * ans2%mod)%mod << endl; // 313818575
cout << (1LL * 672510887 * 313818575)%mod << endl; // 873911579
cout << (1LL * ((1LL * ans2 * ans3)%mod) * ans1) % mod << endl; // 414849507
cout << (1LL * ans1 * (1LL * ans2 * ans3)%mod) % mod << endl; // 935539465
cout << (1LL * ans1 * ((1LL * ans2 * ans3)%mod)) % mod << endl; // 414849507
cout <<  (5 * (3 * 4)%8)%8 << ' ' << (5 * ((3 * 4)%8))%8 << endl; // 4 4
}
```

Comment: Please don't show images of code, or text in general. Copy-paste the code and text into the body of your question instead. Therefore http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Wanted to include the output also, hence the picture. Will keep this mind.

Comment: Furthermore, please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I also recommend you read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and all the rest of http://idownvotedbecau.se/

Comment: Edited the question. Hope it's fine now. @Someprogrammerdude

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `*` and `%` have equal precedence and left-right associative. So an expression like `a * b%c * d` means `((a * b) % c) * d)`.

```
// Undefined behaviour: integer overflow
cout << 1LL*ans1*ans2*ans3 << endl;

// Works out ans1 x ans2 (modulo mod) correctly
cout << 1LL * ( 1LL * ans1%mod * ans2%mod)%mod << endl;

// Works out ans1 x ans1 x ans2 (modulo mod) correctly
cout << (1LL * 672510887 * 313818575)%mod << endl;

// Works out ans1 x ans2 x ans3 (modulo mod) correctly
cout << (1LL * ((1LL * ans2 * ans3)%mod) * ans1) % mod << endl;

// Undefined behaviour due to integer overflow: ans1*ans2*ans3 occurs before the mod
cout << (1LL * ans1 * (1LL * ans2 * ans3)%mod) % mod << endl;

// Works out ans1 x ans2 x ans3 (modulo mod) correctly
cout << (1LL * ans1 * ((1LL * ans2 * ans3)%mod)) % mod << endl;
```

Not sure what the purpose of the last line was; `(5 * (3 * 4)%8)%8` means `(5*3*4)%8` as explained above. Which coincidentally to give the same result as `(5 * ((3*4)%8))%8` for these specific values.

Comment: There is no such thing as 'left-right associative'. There is 'left-associative' and 'right-associative', and all C++ operators are the former.

Comment: Thanks a ton @M.M ! the last line was because of my confusion with the precedence rules. Everything makes sense now!

Comment: @EJP it's common to say "left-to-right" (or shortened to "left-right") for "left-associative, and "right-to-left" etc. for right-associative

Comment: No,it is *not* common to say that. It is an abuse of standard terminology. It is common to say left- or right-associative.